# Read from a channel or timeout?

Tags: multithreading, rust, channel

With Rust 1.9, I'd like to read from a `mpsc::channel` *or* timeout. Is there a clear idiom to make this work? I've seen the unstable approach described in [`mpsc::Select`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Select.html) but [this Github discussion](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27800) suggests it is not a robust approach. Is there a better-recommended way for me to achieve receive-or-timeout semantics?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rust 1.12 introduced [`Receiver::recv_timeout`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#method.recv_timeout):

```
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let (.., rx) = channel::<bool>();
    let timeout = Duration::new(3, 0);

    println!("start recv");
    let _ = rx.recv_timeout(timeout);
    println!("done!");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how you'd do it with the standard library channels, but the [chan crate](https://crates.io/crates/chan) provides a `chan_select!` macro:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate chan;

use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let (_never_sends, never_receives) = chan::sync::<bool>(1);
    let timeout = chan::after(Duration::from_millis(50));

    chan_select! {
        timeout.recv() => {
            println!("timed out!");
        },
        never_receives.recv() => {
            println!("Shouldn't have a value!");
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get something working using the standard lib.

```
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;
use std::thread;
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};
use std::sync::mpsc::TryRecvError;


fn main() {
    let (send, recv) = channel();

    thread::spawn(move || {
        send.send("Hello world!").unwrap();
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)); // block for two seconds
        send.send("Delayed").unwrap();
    });

    println!("{}", recv.recv().unwrap()); // Received immediately
    println!("Waiting...");

    let mut resolved: bool = false;
    let mut result: Result<&str, TryRecvError> = Ok("Null");

    let now = Instant::now();
    let timeout: u64= 2;

    while !resolved {
        result = recv.try_recv();
        resolved = !result.is_err();
        if now.elapsed().as_secs() as u64 > timeout {
            break;
        }
    }

    if result.is_ok(){
        println!("Results: {:?}", result.unwrap());
    }

    println!("Time elapsed: {}", now.elapsed().as_secs());
    println!("Resolved: {}", resolved.to_string());
}
```

This will spin for *timeout* seconds and will result in either the received value or an Err Result.